# Entity Framework - Cascade deleting

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity, cascade

Let's assume I have got 2 classes :

```
public class Photo 
{
     public int Id {get;set;}
     public string Name {get;set;}
     public int AlbumId {get;set;

     publiv virtual Album Album {get;set;}
}

public class Album
{
     public int Id {get;set;}
     public decimal Price {get;set;}

     public ICollection<Photo> Photos {get;set;}
}
```

Now i want to delete all albums with price for example 2. I have tried :

```
Context.RemoveRange(Context.Albums.Where(x = > x.Price == 2))
```

It would be fine, but before deleting the Albums I need to delete every photo with AlbumId I want to delete.

Answer (score 1):

use Fluent API in Context to apply Cascade deleting

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Photo>()
                        .HasRequired(c => c.Album)
                        .WithMany(a => a.Photoes)
                        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Comment: Let's say on my project purposes I need to have this option off :d

Comment: Then you will be deleting them

Answer (score 1):

EF does not do cascade deletes itself.  It relies on the database definition to be correct, and then assumes that the database will perform cascade deletes if specified. See [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/08/19/tip-33-how-cascade-delete-really-works-in-ef.aspx) for more info.  You will have to use Fluent as the other user pointed out, EF does not do that on its own.